# Excel Power Query duplicate OData Requests

Tags: excel, odata, powerquery

I am using *Power Query* to get data from one of the OData services for reporting purposes. It seemed really easy till I found out, that it does 3 or 4 OData GET-requests every time I update the report.

This is not acceptable for me due to performance issues.

I tried it with and without parameters in my OData URL and as a test I deleted all steps in my query to see if they cause the duplicate calls, but nothing worked. I found a few posts where people had similar issues but not a single answer.

Is this normal behavior or linked to my Query/OData service?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a chain of several PQ queries that refer to each other (q1 > q2  > q3... etc), PQ executes each of them several times instead of using previously received data. Try to make one big query that contain all q1..qN as steps, not as separate queries